# Django Relation between two models

Tags: django

I am very new to Django.

Can you please give a boilerplate of models how to relate two models between each other.

--Below is Section model

```
from articles.models import Article
# Create your models here.
class Section(models.Model): 
    #associations
    user    = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article) #Article
```

--Below is Article model

```
from sections.models import Section
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    owner       =models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    sections = models.ManyToManyField( Section )
```

However. I got the below error:
ValueError: Cannot create form field for 'article' yet, because its related model 'articles.models' has not been loaded yet

Thanks All

B

Comment: You here have defined a *cyclic* import.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Breaking cyclic imports

You defined a cyclic import: one module first has to import the other module, but the other module fist has to implement that module, so you defined a cycle.

In Django, one does *not* per se has to use a class reference to make `ForeignKey`s, one can use *strings* that refer to the correct model. In that case the Django framework, will later resolve these.

So we can break the cycle, for example with:

```
# sections/models.py

# no import from articles

# Create your models here.
class Section(models.Model): 
    #associations
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    # we use a string literal
    article = models.ForeignKey('articles.Article', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and then in the `articles/models.py`:

```
# articles/models.py

from sections.models import Section
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    sections = models.ManyToManyField(Section)
```

So here we no longer import `articles/models.py` in the `sections/models.py`, and thus we break the cyclic import.

Note that you need to specify an `on_delete` for a `ForeignKey`, for example `models.CASCADE`.

## Django's reverse relations

For this specific application however, it seems that you make a double relation between `Section` and `Article`, that basically is one relation, you should *not* do that, Django automatically writes the reverse relation, what you probably want to do, is give it a proper name, for example:

```
# sections/models.py

# no import from articles

# Create your models here.
class Section(models.Model): 
    #associations
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    # we use a string literal
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        'articles.Article',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='sections'
    )
```

and for `articles/models.py`:

```
# articles/models.py

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    # no relation to section
```

Here we can obtain all `Section`s that relate to `some_article` with `some_article.sections.all()`.